# What materials are used to make up a combustion chamber?

Tags: jet-engine, aerospace-materials, combustion

What type of materials are used to make up the different sections such as the linings of the combustion chambers in a gas turbine engine. Do these type of materials vary for the different types of gas turbine Engines such as the multiple-can type, annular and cannular.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about combustor liners specifically (as opposed to the hot section in general), the ones I am familiar with are cobalt-based superalloys.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an engineering question than an aviation question, but since some aviators may be interested in knowing exactly what is in those turbines I will answer.

There are three main types of refractory alloys commonly used for high-temperature components in turbine engines. They are:

ODS ([oxide dispersion strengthened superalloys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxide_dispersion-strengthened_alloy))
CMC ([ceramic matrix composites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_matrix_composite))
[intermetallic post transition alloys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermetallic)

Of the intermetallics that are used, there are two main types commonly used: NiAl (nickel aluminum) and TiAl (titanium aluminum).